# How to get body message in HttpErrorResponse?

Tags: angular

I call the service method that makes server request:

```
 this.applicationBuildingsService
            .create(this.application.appid)
             handleResponseMessage(this.messageService))
            .subscribe((response: Building) => {});
```

Where `handleResponseMessage` is:

```
export const handleResponseMessage = (
    messageService: MessageService,
    message = { success: 'Операция прошла успешно!', error: 'Операция прошла неуспешно!' },
) =>
    pipe(
        tap((response: any) => {
            messageService.showMessage('', response?.message || message.success, 'success');
        }),

        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
            messageService.showMessage('', error?.message || message.error, 'error');
            return throwError(error);
        }),
    );
```

Where server returns an error (not 2xx status) I try to get json body from server with message error inside:

```
 catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {}
```

But `HttpErrorResponse` has no body property

Comment: Have you checked the documentation (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse#error)? Seems like the "error" property holds the error.

Comment: Yes, but it returns system error instead body JSON from server

Comment: Does the error response contain a JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter: `{ observe: 'response' }`, let you read the full response including the headers. See the below description:-

Tell HttpClient that you want the full response with the observe option:

```
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
    return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}
```